# ASP.NET Core SelectList not binding if value is string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core-mvc

```
ViewData["ComponenteId"] = new SelectList(await GetComponentes(Geometria.MatrizId), "Nome", "Nome", Geometria.Componente);
```

here is the view

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="Geometria.Componente" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="Geometria.Componente" class="custom-select" asp-items="ViewBag.ComponenteId">
            <option value="">Selecione um Componente</option>
        </select>
        <span asp-validation-for="Geometria.Componente" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

no matter what it won't bind and i don't understand why when basically the value and text are the same property.

this is how it is rendered in html

```
<select class="custom-select input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Componente POE field is required." id="Geometria_Componente" name="Geometria.Componente" aria-describedby="Geometria_Componente-error" aria-invalid="true">
    <option value="">Selecione um Componente</option>
    <option value="M130291">M130291</option>
    <option value="M130559">M130559</option>
    <option value="M140004">M140004</option>
    <option value="M140040">M140040</option>
    <option value="SA00367A300">SA00367A300</option>
    <option value="SS98940A100">SS98940A100</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE**

It seems the reason it was not binding it is because the value had whitespaces even before i started using Entity Framework Core. The old data type was varchar hence why it was not recognizing it.